# proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation How to use Custom Rule Messages?

Tags: laravel, validation, jsvalidation

I use [proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation) in combination with a custom FormRequest and custom validation rules that I defined via Validator::extend(...) in a service provider. This works well.

However, when I port my custom rules to the new(ish) custom Rule class in Laravel 5.5+, JsValidator fails at getting my custom Rule messages.

I have this custom rule:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class MyRule implements Rule 
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value) {
        return $value > 10;
    }
    public function message() {
        return 'Your :attribute is pretty small, dawg!';
    }
}
```

My form request uses this rule:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Rules\MyRule;

class MyRequest extends FormRequest 
{
    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules() {
        $rules = [
            'foo' => 'required|numeric',
            'bar' => ['required', new MyRule()],
        ];
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

This should work, but I get thrown an Exception on

```
{!! JsValidator::formRequest('\App\Http\Requests\MyRequest') !!}
```

An Exception is thrown from a call to Str::snake(Object(App\Rules\MyRule)) made by Proengsoft\JsValidation\Javascript\MessageParser.php.

JsValidation does not look at the $rule object type before calling Validator->getMessage($attribute, $rule)
where instead it should be calling $rule->messages();

Can I work around this bug somehow, and use laravel-jsvalidation together with my custom Rule and FormRequest -- or does it necessarily require i make a pull request and hope it will be fixed... someday? I'd like to make this work now-ish.

Answer (score 0):

This can be archived by passing  **JsValidator instance based on rules and message arrays** instead of passing the form request.  In controller Pass this instance to blade. Read [here](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/wiki/Facade#jsvalidatormake) for more details.

```
JsValidator::make($rules, $messages, $customAttributes, $selector)
```

In controller,

```
$validator = JsValidator::make(
    [
        'name' => 'required',
    ],
    [
        'name.required' => 'Name field is a required field',
    ]
)

return View::make("Your view", compact($validator));
```

In blade,

```
{!! $validator->selector('.wizard_frm') !!}

<form class='wizard_frm'></form>
```

And in this case we can create object of request class and pass rules function returned array to `JsValidator::make` if needed.